# Burninate the meta tags {help} and {features}?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I found two tags here on meta that might be considered meta tags and, thus, should be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/163868). What is your opinion of the following?

- [help](/questions/tagged/help)
- [features](/questions/tagged/features)

[image: Meta Trogdor, I call upon you!]

Comment: I think the tags have low number of questions tagged to them. We can just remove the tag from the question, no?

Comment: @jokerdino Aye, I just wanted to get others opinions.

Answer (score 9):

I definitely think that [help](/questions/tagged/help) should be banned. Because it doesn't add anything to the question. It's like having a Ubuntu tag.

Comment: Should we have another tag, then, for questions where people ask about how to get help with Ubuntu (but which don't fit on meta because they are not about AskUbuntu per se), or how to use Ubuntu's help and documentation facilities?

Comment: @EliahKagan Help with what? tagging help will just confuse the question. The Ubuntu help page should be called the Ubuntu documentation. so there is no point of a help tag.

Comment: @EliahKagan The help facility has a tag, "yelp", and docs are "documentation".

Comment: Sounds like we can do pretty easily without "help" then.

Comment: It looks like this never got acted on at the time. It was brought up again last month: [I need some \[help\] getting rid of this tag from Ask Ubuntu Meta!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20089/1406746) – That discussion was acted on, and it was then burninated.