# Please block the [help] tag on AU Meta

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, meta, tag-block-request

Could CMs please block the [help](/questions/tagged/help) tag on AU Meta.

Following [Shog9's guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/662263), we have accomplished the prerequisites:

1. **Burninate the tag:** A combination of myself and the community have edited out the tag and substituted the more relevant tags.
2. **Decide if it needs to be blocked:** This was discussed some time ago [Burninate the meta tags {help} and {features}?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3217/57576) at a time shortly after the tag was blocked on the main AU. (The term 'banned' was used rather than the term 'blocked' in the answer.) The tag has *reappeared* subsequently and is *still not welcome* on Meta.
3. **Discuss if the tag is relevant:** [Recent conversation on Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20089/57576) has reinforced the lack of relevance of this tag on Meta. You will note the community support in the form of up votes in the discussion.
4. **Moderator involvement and status-review:** I *strongly* support the removal and blocking of this tag from AU Meta (note its removal and blocking on the main AU site) and have create this separate post, as requested by JNat, and added the status-review tag.

Please let me know if any more is required...

**References:**

- [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/662263) – Shog9's definitive guide to the blocking of unwanted tags on SO.
- [I need some [help] getting rid of this tag from Ask Ubuntu Meta!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20089/57576) – Cocomac's recent post on removal of the tag with community support and discussion.

Comment: ...Has the tag actually sprung up again (after being burninated) on this meta? Aside from the "Recent conversation on Meta" link in your post, I did find one previous post specifically about getting rid of the [meta-tag:help] tag from this meta site: [Burninate the meta tags {help} and {features}?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3217/1406746) – but nothing in that discussion seems to indicate it was acted on. Any other past discussions on Ask Ubuntu Meta seem to be about the `help` tag on the main Ask Ubuntu site (which is already blocked), not on this Meta.

Comment: @V2Blast The help tag on Meta has not been recreated since the burnination, which looks like it was 7 days ago or so. And looks like you have given the correct Meta discussion that spoke of ridding the help tag from Meta, back in 2012. So this one plus the recent discussion in Meta: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20089/57576, I have scrambled myself with the several posts talking about ridding AU itself of the tag :(

Comment: I have placed the correct link in my question, thanks for pointing out this one @V2Blast...

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment above, the tag hasn't actually been recreated since it was blocked, so there doesn't appear to be a need to block the tag at this time.

If it does end up getting inappropriately recreated, feel free to raise a new request to block the tag at that time. (You should wait to get consensus from the community before adding the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the post, however.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I will keep an eye out for any return of this tag...